# Solve $\sum_{k=1}^{2n} \binom{4n}{2k}$

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

$\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{2n} \binom{4n}{2k}$
I thought that

=$\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{4n!}{2k!(4n-2k)!}$=$\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{n!}{k!(2n-k)!}$
but I don't understand what to do next, and how does the fact that k =1 and not 0 affect here?

Comment: Have you tried some small values of n and evaluating manually? Maybe some pattern will emerge that you can try and extrapolate a general form for

Comment: Perhaps one day people will understand the difference between 'solve' and 'compute'.

Comment: Hint:  What is $(1-1)^{4n}$?  If you do this directly vs if you do this by binomial theorem?  What does this imply?  How about $(1+1)^{4n}$?

Comment: "*How does the fact that $k=1$ and not 0 affect here*"  Your sum is just missing the first term compared to what you would ordinarily see in other posts and so is $1$ less than the sum had we started at $k=0$

Comment: So if we use the binomial theorem, I can write like this =$(1+x)^{4n}$, but it turns out that k =1 must be taken into account